# Add a custom database table to the wordpress search

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, search

I have a custom database table for a plugin I wrote for wordpress. Now I want to integrate this table into the wordpress search, since yet the wordpress search shows me just results for the data entered via the core CMS of course.

Preferably I would like to avoid altering the WP core to make this possible.

So is there any way to make this possible or do I have to write my own search function to search and display results for this custom table data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This absolute answer for this, would be pretty custom, depending on what you want to do. But if you understand SQL and databases, this article would be very useful.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class

Comment: yeah, I guess it will result in me writing my own function for it.. Thank you for your answer!